# Need to use host variables in Ansible (ansible engine 2.8 & ansible tower 3.5)

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Need your help in achieving below:
- use variables provided inline with hostIP (i.e. host variables) in Ansible inventory

my inventory:

```
[ora_patch]
10.24.29.14 SID=orcl,orcl2
```

my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: [ora_patch]
  tasks:
  - debug:
     var: "{{ hostvars[ansible_host]['SID'] }}"
```

### Output ** I GET **:

```
PLAY [ora_patch] ************************************************************

TASK [patch_ora_si_122 : debug] *****************************************
ok: [10.24.29.14] => {
    "orcl,orcl2": "(Undefined, Undefined)"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
10.24.29.14               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

### Output ** I want ** :

```
PLAY [ora_patch] ***********************************************************

TASK [patch_ora_si_122 : debug] ****************************************
ok: [10.24.29.14] => {
    "SID": "orcl,orcl2"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************
10.24.29.14               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Command I execute:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory patch_ora_si_122.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your playbook is slightly wrong. You are trying to use the content of the hostvar `"{{ hostvars[ansible_host]['SID'] }}"` as a variable name to display with `debug: var=...`.

Simply change your playbook to

```
---
- hosts: ora_patch
  tasks:
  - debug:
     msg: "SID: {{ hostvars[ansible_host]['SID'] }}"
```

or you could also use the variable name directly:

```
---
- hosts: ora_patch
  tasks:
  - debug:
     var: SID
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible inventory.ini follows beloe format.

```
[hosts]

[hosts:vars]
```

**The below should work:**

```
[ora_patch]
10.24.29.14 SID=orcl,orcl2

[ora_patch:vars]
SID=orcl,orcl2
```